Issue with Wi-Fi connection in Buildroot using WPA2-PSK
I'm currently working with Buildroot to create a custom embedded system for my raspberry pi zero w , and I'm encountering an issue when trying to configure Wi-Fi with WPA2-PSK. I have configured my /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf file and my /etc/network/interfaces, but for some reason, the system is not connecting to Wi-Fi.
Configuration:
Here are my rootfs overlays /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf:
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=1
country=DE

network={
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    ssid="secret"
    psk="secret"

}

And my rootfs overlays /etc/network/interfaces configuration looks like this:
# Local loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Ethernet interface (eth0) with DHCP
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Wireless interface (wlan0) with DHCP, WPA Supplicant configuration
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    pre-up wpa_supplicant -D nl80211 -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
    post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
    wait-delay 15

This is my config
https://pastebin.com/5DAsjPTb
Issue:
The system is not establishing a Wi-Fi connection when using this configuration.

Welcome -- but you will need to explain how ifup is being run, since it (and ifdown) are what use /etc/network/interfaces (otherwise it is meaningless).  Often these are in scripts used by higher level networking services, but you don't refer to anything, so one obvious implication based on the information given is no connection is established because no attempt is made to establish one.
